# Not to get new data from server with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I has a site based on Ember.js. This site has a textarea where models' field `message` is set. When user changes this field I make `model.save()`. Everything is ok but one thing: if I write something while save API request is not finished, text will be flushed to the version been saved to server.
How to explain to Ember that I want to use client version of this field, not server version?
Sorry for my english :(

Comment: are you talking about a concurrency issue where the data on the server has changed?

Comment: @ctcpip It si in global, but now I want to solve a particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ember-changeset](https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset) would solve that.

Check this video out in emberscreencasts, it is a good explanation of what the problem it solves and how it works: https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/168-introduction-to-ember-changeset